# Should/Can you run Node-OPCUA Server running on Azure?

Tags: node.js, azure, opc, opc-ua, node-opcua

I deployed my OPC Server (made with Node.js [node-opcua](http://node-opcua.github.io/)) on Azure as a WebApp and its running. I also got the opc.tcp address (eg. opc.tcp://somenumbers:4840/UA/INDUSTRIE4.0) . When I try to connect to it with [UaExpert](https://www.unified-automation.com/de/produkte/entwicklerwerkzeuge/uaexpert.html) I get this error:

> Discovery FindServersOnNetwork on opc.tcp://somenumbers:4840 failed
>   (BadHostUnknown), falling back to FindServers
>
> [uastack] OpcUa_P_ParseUrl: OpcUa_P_RawSocket_InetAddr reports error
>   0x81060000.

What am I doing wrong? Is TCP connection on Azure only possible in the same Network?

Comment: I do not quite get this part: " The Server g... writes/reads to/from the Client." An OPC Server is the "passive" part in the Client-Server model: it is the Client that can read/write from/to the server.

Comment: @ZbynekZ The OPC server sets its variables (Endpoints) and write something in them. And also listen to changes to its own endpoints. So it can read and write to those endpoints. And the client can access those endpoints defined by the server and also read and write them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Answer is: Only port 80 and 443 of the tcp are open on an azure web app. What you need is a virtual machine or activating VNET in the network options. This is only possible if you have a Windows Machine.

Answer (score 2):

Yes as you said in your answer port 80 and 443 are open for web app.

Additional to your option with virtual machine you should be able to set up a container.
Like Azure Container Instances or Service Fabric Mesh container. (if you don't want to run a cluster like aks).